# como puedo hacerle para al dar clic sobre menú me muestre un checklist programación web

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

Buen día a todos!
Espero me puedan ayudar, soy nuevo en esto de la programación web.

Tengo un menu hecho en html y css. Quiero que cuando de click sobre alguno de sus elementos me muestre en el centro de la pagina, un check list que al escoger alguna de sus opciones me mande a traer la información desde la base de datos.

- ¿Qué código se ocupa para este evento?
- ¿Es "onclick" el evento para que me muestre la información según la
  opción elegida en el menú?
- ¿Qué código podría ocupar para hacer el checklist?
- ¿Cómo hago para que no me mande otra página, sino que en la
  misma pagina me muestre la información?

Éste es el código que llevo hasta ahora:

```
<body>
<header>
<img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\pagina\maestro-y-estudiante.gif" alt="Computer Man" style="width:48px;height:48px;" align="right"> 
</header>

        <div id="menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="..." title="...">Calificaciones</a></li>
  <li><a href="..." title="...">Reportes</a></li>
  <li><a href="..." title="...">Acerca de</a></li>
  <li><a href="..." title="...">Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<input id="activar" name="activar" type="checkbox">
<label class="inputlabel" for="activar">Clic para ver contenido</label>
<div class="desplegable">
  Aquí podría ir cualquier tipo de elemento
</div>
```

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda ya que estoy haciendo un proyecto escolar y necesito de ésto ya que no soy ningún programador experto y aún no tomo ningún curso de programación web gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español , primero, te recomiendo que investigues un poco sobre Javascript, y en particular Jquery . Mediante éstos lenguajes puedes empezar a darle dinamismo a tu página, que es lo que estás buscando. luego de entender los conceptos generales de como trabajan éstas tecnologías, averigua específicamente cada situación que se te vaya presentando: **Divide y Vencerás**

Saludos!

Comment: con Jquery puedes añadir y quitar clases a un elemento del dom ya que con eso puedes ocultar o mostrar tu checklist

Comment: muchas gracias  seguiré investigando entonces!